# Why does nitration of N,N-dimethylaniline occur at the meta position?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds

The nitration of *N*,*N*-dimethylaniline with $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$ gives mainly the *meta* product, even though $\ce{-NMe2}$ is an *ortho*,*para*-directing group. Why is this so?

[image: Reaction]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetryl - reaction can proceed in other way

Comment: The best way around this issue, from a reagent/yield point of view, is to use acetic anhydride to N-acetylate the primary amine. This gives acetanilide, the acetyl derivative of aniline.

Comment: Essentially a dupe: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31644/how-is-anilinium-ion-meta-directing-for-electrophiles

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the presence of these strong acids the $\ce{-NMe2}$ group is protonated, and the protonated form is [electron-withdrawing *via* the inductive effect](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31644/how-is-the-nh3-substituent-meta-directing-in-electrophilic-substitution). This discourages attack at the electron-poor *ortho* position.

Under the conditions I know for that experiment, you get a mixture of *para*- and *meta*-product, but no ortho-product due to steric hindrance.

Answer (score 23):

In these acidic conditions, the lone pair on the nitrogen will abstract a proton of the acid in an acid-base fashion. This protonated amine will then be considered a meta-directing group. It is a deactivator that will draw electron density away from the ring (because nitrogen, a relatively electronegative atom, will have a positive charge).

The best way to get around this is to N-acylate. This can be done by first reacting the mono-substituted amine with acetic chloride ($\ce{CH3COCl}$) with pyridine to get an amide. That way, the ring is still activated and the lone pair on the amide nitrogen will not interfere with acids. It will direct ortho-para (para favored due to sterics).