# Is the ammonium substituent (-NH3+) really meta-directing in electrophilic substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, amines, regioselectivity

If we make a resonance structure for the anilinium ion, with positive charge at either the *ortho* or the *para* position, we get a pentavalent nitrogen, which is not possible. So, how is the $\ce{-NH3+}$ group *meta*-directing in electrophilic aromatic substitution reactions, e.g. in nitration of aniline under acidic conditions?

Answer (score 37):

> how is anilinium ion meta directing for electrophiles?

Actually, **anilinium is not meta directing** (I know it is often taught that way), but rather it inductively deactivates the entire aromatic ring.

To explain the electrophilic substitution pattern observed with any aromatic system we must consider both resonance and inductive effects.

**Resonance Effects:** You are correct that you can't delocalize the positive charge on the anilinium nitrogen into the benzene ring through resonance.  As you point out, resonance structures with 5 bonds to nitrogen aren't allowed.

[image]

Therefore **resonance effects are not involved in explaining the reactivity of the anilinium ion towards electrophilic aromatic substitution**.

**Inductive Effects:** Inductively we expect the anilinium nitrogen to strongly withdraw electron density from the *ortho* position since it is closest to the positively charged nitrogen, this makes the *ortho* position the most deactivated.  Inductive effects die off quickly with distance, so we would expect the *meta* position to also be deactivated, but less so than the *ortho* position.  Finally, we would still expect some deactivation at the distant *para* position, but slightly less than we saw at the *meta* position. Overall, in terms of reactivity we would expect *para* > *meta* > *ortho*, with the difference between *para* and *meta* being much smaller than the difference between *meta* and *ortho* due to the effect distance has on inductive electron withdrawal.

If we examine the nitration of aniline in strong acid ($\ce{HNO3}$, $\ce{H2SO4}$), under these conditions the strong acid will completely protonate the aniline and reaction will proceed through the anilinium ion.  We see that, as expected, there is very little *ortho* product and slightly more *para* product than *meta* product.  This is pretty much as we expected and is **consistent with the electron withdrawing inductive effect of the positive anilinium nitrogen**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please also comment on the directing nature of $\ce{-NR3+}$ (not $\ce{-NH3+}$)? Would here the inductive effects of the three alkyl groups make this group meta directing somehow? Is there experimental evidence related to this? Thanks!

Comment: @GaurangTandon Since what you ask is a different question from the OP, you may want to post it as a new question.  I haven't searched the $\ce{Ph-NR3^{+}}$ case, but my intuition tells me that it would behave similarly to $\ce{Ph-NH3^{+}}$

Comment: No @ron, it doesn't ... (Source: March's Advanced Organic Chemistry) only $\ce{NH3+}$ is an exception rest all ($\ce{NR3+ , NHR2+}$) etc are meta directing...I am unable to rationalise this.

Comment: @Abcd Did you happen to post a question about this exception? (And which page in March?)