# Why is Aniline a poor substrate for Nitration reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nitro-compounds

I have been asked to find out which one of the following is a poor substrate for Nitration reaction:

> [image]

Upon encountering this question, my first reaction was the option *c*, as I know that the nitration mechanism involves the substitution of a positively charged Nitronium ion ($\ce{NO2+}$) and hence a $\ce{-OCOCH_3}$ group that shows $\mathrm{-M}$ effect will not be helpful for that process as it reduces the electron density in the benzene ring.

But the solution states that the answer is aniline (given in option *a*). I do not understand how is that possible. Even in the case when we use mixed acid as the reagent, it will form para- and meta-substituted nitro compounds. But, I do not know why and how does it behave as a 'poor substrate' in any case of nitration.

Please explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of option *c*, the $\ce{-OCOCH_3}$ group will not be showing $\mathrm{-M}$ effect as the ring is directly attached to the oxygen atom. The group rather shows $\mathrm{+M}$ effect because of the two lone pairs present on the oxygen atom, increasing the electron density in the benzene ring and thus making it a good substrate for a nitration reaction.

On the other hand, as nitration is generally done with mixed acid as the reagent, the $\ce{-NH_2}$ group in aniline takes up a hydrogen atom to become $\ce{-NH_3^+}$,  [which is a ring deactivating group](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31650/39388).

Therefore, among the options given, aniline is the poorest substrate for nitration reactions.

Comment: You're making it simpler then it is. Aniline tends to oxidise, forming oligomers, unless you completely protonate it.

Comment: @Mithoron I am a high school student, so my logical reasoning is bound by my limited knowledge of the subject. It would be great if you could explain your point in detail (maybe as a separate answer or provide links to resources).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyaniline https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniline