# Can -NH2 groups get nitrated?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In the chapter of amines, and I see reaction occuring between amines and nitrous acid. However I am thinking why I don't see reactions of amines also react $\ce{HNO3}$ in presence of stronger acid like $\ce{H2SO4}$, that can protonate $\ce{HNO3}$, causes $\ce{H2O}$ to leave and then finally have amines to react with $\ce{NO2}$, making **nitroamines**?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7/why-does-nitration-of-n-n-dimethylaniline-occur-at-the-meta-position

Comment: Yeah, but in the link, I don't see amine reacting together with HNO3 per say like the way amine react with nitrous acid.

Comment: You mean if amine group can be nitrated?

Comment: Yes, like how you create N-nitrosamine.

Comment: My first comment there

Comment: ahh... okay. So why is this nitration of amine group not taught in orgo books? Is it because of hazardous issues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58465/discussion-between-tlo-and-mithoron).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can form a nitroamine (nitramine) from a secondary amine and nitric/sulfuric acids. Some explosives have a nitramine structure (e.g. tetryl, RDX, HMX, HNIW).